# CSS animations on <span>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a CSS animation to a `<span>` element and I just can't get it to work. I can't find any resource that says whether animations can be applied to `<span>` elements. So, is it me that is making an error, or are spans animation immune?

Edit: Code

```
Inf<span class="inf_o">o</span>rmation
    <br>
do<span class="don_n">n</span>e
    <br>
we<span class="dbl_l">ll</span>
```

and css:

```
/* animations */
.inf_o 
{
  -webkit-animation-name: lower_head;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: active;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes lower_head
{
  from {margin-top:0px;}
  to {margin-top:10px;}
}
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with your current code, or post it here?

Comment: may be you have to define display:block in your css for span

Comment: put up the code in the edit. It does work when I specify display:block; Is there a way to do this can be done with out block elements. I would like to avoid numerous floats and clears.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

looks like you have to set a display property. Obviously block will mess up the word, so you need to use inline. I cooked up a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jdmiller82/XWkRX/1/

As you can see the 'o' animates down.

Comment: Display inline didn't work for me but inline-block did, as per your jsfiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

just add `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time getting my span animation to work.  In my case, the page loads with the span's `display` set to `none`.  I tried many work-arounds but the one that worked in the end (unfortunately) was removing the `display: none` from css and hiding it when the page loads.

In case it matters, I am using jQuery to hide/show the span.